# INNER JOIN if table 1 has 2 rows matching in table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't exactly know how to word this question correctly, so I'll start with the data because I think it will make more sense that way.

Starting with these two tables:

```
Table 1:
user_id | equipment_id
------ | ------
1      | 2
1      | 3
1      | 6
2      | 2
2      | 6

Table 2:
equipment_id | exercise_id
------ | ------
2      | 1
3      | 2
6      | 2
```

I would like to create this third table:

```
Table 3:
user_id | exercise_id
------ | ------
1      | 1
1      | 2
2      | 1
```

It seems like a simple INNER JOIN to get the data, but I'm running into trouble with the second row. I only want that row to show up if user_id 1 has both pieces of equipment listed in Table 2. If either piece of equipment is missing, I don't want the data inserted as shown by user_id 2. I also want to make sure I don't get two instances of user_id 1 for each piece of equipment.

This is the code I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (user_id, exercise_id) 
SELECT user_id, exercise_id 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table2.equipment_id = Table1.equipment_id
```

The result I get is this with the rows that need to be removed indicated:

```
Table 3:
user_id | exercise_id
 ------ | ------
 1      | 1
 1      | 2
 1      | 2 <--- duplicate of row above
 2      | 1
 2      | 2 <--- user 2 doesn't have equipment 3, so shouldn't be included
```

Any help on limiting the results would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think your sample data and expected output don't match. Can you reverify?

Comment: I think your relation is not correct, because your tables has not any relation to show which user has exercise and which is not.

Comment: *user_id 1 has both pieces of equipment* - Can you clarify what you mean? the table2 has 3 equipments

Comment: What is the logic behind your expected result set?  I can't think of any logic which would arrive at this.

Comment: Either your database structure is complicated or you need to clarify more ,I recommend to manage your database first and reduce the complexity ..level.

Comment: I've added my answer below, but the code may not work on MySQL. I tested it on SQL-Server, and you tagged both. It might be worth you removing the one you aren't using. Actually ... having just re-tested, it seems to run on MySQL too (though the code on rextester needs semi-colons adding to the end of each statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to retrieve all the exercises for a user where all the equipment required for that exercise is "available" to the user. I've put some code over at [rextester.com/AYRE74108](http://rextester.com/AYRE74108). The important part of that looks like this:

```
select distinct
    t1.user_id,
    t2.exercise_id
from
    table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON
    t1.equipment_id = t2.equipment_id
where
    not exists
   (select 1
    from
        table_2 t2b
    where
        t2b.exercise_id = t2.exercise_id
        AND not exists (select 1
                        from
                            table_1 t1b
                        where
                            t2b.equipment_id = t1b.equipment_id
                            AND t1.user_id = t1b.user_id)
    )
```

To explain the logic: I begin with the standard join and `distinct`. But then I require that there `NOT EXIST` any piece of equipment required for the exercise such that that user/equipment combination does `NOT EXIST`. This is equivalent to saying the user has to have "available" (listed in table 1) all the equipment required for the exercise.

Or schematically: "ALL X are Y" === "NO X is such that Not Y".

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the last row of your output should not be 2 | 2 but 1 | 2.

Also using distinct will ensure that there will be no duplicate rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, exercise_id 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table2.equipment_id = Table1.equipment_id
```

Edit - The mistake in the question threw me off. This should work.

```
SELECT user_id, table2.exercise_id , sum(table2.equipment_id), sum(b.equipment_id)
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table2.equipment_id = Table1.equipment_id
inner join table2 as b
on table2.exercise_id = b.exercise_id
group by user_id, table2.exercise_id
having sum(table2.equipment_id)= sum(b.equipment_id)
```

Comment: You are correct. I mistyped the final row of Table 1. I've corrected my mistake, so it should make more sense.

Thank you for your help. I will see if I can make that work in the specific situation.

Comment: Doesn't this fail to remove the 2 | 2 row?

Comment: That row came up only after the edit in the question, i have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: That looks better. I've removed my downvote. It works for the given dataset, but I'm not entirely convinced it's safe. For example, if an exercise had three required pieces of equipment (ids 1,2,3) and the user had access to only two (1,3) they would still be returned. It would be safer if the `sum(X)` parts were replaced with `sum(distinct X)`.